# Deleting an Azure Active Directory Device via API

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

I am working on an automation to remove devices from InTune and Azure for single users when the laptop or device is being retired. I am trying to make DELETE requests via the graph API to remove the device from AutoPilot, InTune, and Azure Active Directory (AAD).

Currently, this is working for everything except AAD. I am attempting to use the API: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/admin/windows/updates/updatableAssets based on information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/windowsupdates-updatableasset-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent that I can find outside of beta. I am able to make a GET request to list items but trying to retrieve or delete a single item keeps giving me a 404.

Does anyone have any solutions for removing an Azure AD Device via API?

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried Version selector as shown in the MSDN?

although i don't have similar scenario to test, but URl might be like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/windows/updates/updatableAssets/{updatableAssetId}
```

One more way, if you have the option of using `GraphServiceClient`, then you can use this

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/windowsupdates-updatableasset-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp
```

Best part of the `GraphServiceClient` is default it will prepare a General Release version Api to call.

MSDN:-`Microsoft Graph SDKs use the v1.0 version of the API by default, and do not support all the types, properties, and APIs available in the beta version`

Please check at your end, if the GA is providing the operation you are looking for.

Comment: I appreciate this information. I tried to find the v1.0 version but it doesn't look it exists yet, so I might just have to wait for this feature. GraphServiceClient would be great but I am calling this API through ServiceNow, so I am limited to JavaScript, unfortunately.